# How to create rabbit listeners using spring AMQP to listen to queues across multiple vhosts

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have multiple virtual hosts each with a request queue and a response queue. These virtual hosts serve different clients. The names for the request queue and the response queue remain the same across the virtual hosts.

I have created a SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory with the clientName()+"ConnectionFactory" as the lookup key and a corresponding CachingConnectionFactory as the value in the map. I'm able to publish message to the request queues by binding and the RabbitTemplate to a virtual host before convertAndSend and then unbinding it.

I'm not able to consume messages from the response queues from different virtual hosts. I have created a SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory for each client. I implemented RabbitListenerConfigurer and registered a SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint for each SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory. I also set the connectionFactory on each SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory as the client's CachingConnectionFactory.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private ClientList clients;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory routingConnectionFactory() {
        final var routingConnectionFactory = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
        final Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> routeMap = new HashMap<>();
        applicationContext.getBeansOfType(ConnectionFactory.class)
                .forEach((beanName, bean) -> {
                    routeMap.put(beanName, bean);
                });
        routingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactories(routeMap);
        return routingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(routingConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange orbitExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("orbit-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue requestQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder
                .durable("request-queue")
                .lazy()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue responseQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder
                .durable("response-queue")
                .lazy()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding requestBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(requestQueue())
                .to(orbitExchange())
                .with("orbit-request");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding responseBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(responseQueue())
                .to(orbitExchange())
                .with("orbit-response");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
            clients.get()
                    .stream()
                    .forEach(client -> {
                        var endpoint = createEndpoint(client);
                        var listenerContainerFactory = applicationContext.getBean(client.getName() + "ListenerContainerFactory");
                        listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory)applicationContext.getBean(client.getName() + "ConnectionFactory"));
                        registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint, listenerContainerFactory);
                    });
        }
    }

    private SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint createEndpoint(Client client) {
        var endpoint = new SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint();
        endpoint.setId(client.getName());
        endpoint.setQueueNames("response-queue");
        endpoint.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new MessageReceiver(), "receive"));
        return endpoint;
    }

}
```

However, I get `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s). java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]`

I'm not able to figure out whats causing this as I'm not using the SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory for message consumption at all.

**EDIT:**
Full stack trace below -

```
ERROR [2020-07-09T04:12:38,028] [amdoListenerEndpoint-1] [TraceId:] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.determineTargetConnectionFactory(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:120)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.createConnection(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2089)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2062)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2042)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:407)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:391)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1836)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1817)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1349)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**EDIT2:**
I used the routingConnectionFactory with every listener and used the setLookUpKeyQualifier. No more exceptions but, the listeners don't seem to be doing anything i.e., the queues are not being listened to.

```
@Import(MqConfig.class) 
//This is to import CachingConnectinFactory beans and SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory beans for all clients
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private ClientList clients;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory routingConnectionFactory() {
        final var routingConnectionFactory = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
        final Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> routeMap = new HashMap<>();
        applicationContext.getBeansOfType(ConnectionFactory.class)
                .forEach((beanName, bean) -> {
                    routeMap.put(beanName+"[response-queue]", bean);
                });
        routingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactories(routeMap);
        return routingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(routingConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange orbitExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("orbit-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue requestQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder
                .durable("request-queue")
                .lazy()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue responseQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder
                .durable("response-queue")
                .lazy()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding requestBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(requestQueue())
                .to(orbitExchange())
                .with("orbit-request");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding responseBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(responseQueue())
                .to(orbitExchange())
                .with("orbit-response");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
            clients.get()
                    .stream()
                    .forEach(client -> {
                        var endpoint = createEndpoint(client);
                        var listenerContainerFactory = getListenerContainerFactory(Client client);
                        listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory)applicationContext.getBean(client.getName() + "ConnectionFactory"));
                        registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint, listenerContainerFactory);
                    });
        }
    }

    private SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint createEndpoint(Client client) {
        var endpoint = new SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint();
        endpoint.setId(client.getName());
        endpoint.setQueueNames("response-queue");
        endpoint.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new MessageReceiver(), "receive"));
        return endpoint;
    }

    private SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory getListenerContainerFactory(Client client) {
        var listenerContainerFactory =  (SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory) applicationContext.getBean(client.getName() + "ListenerContainerFactory");
        listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(routingConnectionFactory());
        listenerContainerFactory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            container.setQueueNames("response-queue");
            container.setLookupKeyQualifier(client.getName());
            container.setMessageListener(message -> log.info("Received message"));
        });
        return listenerContainerFactory;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something very strange going on; `[null]` implies that when we call `getRoutingLookupKey()` the cf is not a routing cf but when we call `getConnectionFactory()` it is.

It's not obvious how that can happen. Perhaps you can figure out why in a debugger?

One solution would be to inject the routing cf and use `setLookupKeyQualifier(...)`.

The lookup key will then be `clientId[queueName]`.

Comment: Thanks, Gary! I have now used the routingcf in every listener and used the setLookUpKeyQualifier(...). See my EDIT2 above. No more exceptions but, the listeners are not listening. Something to do with the way I have implemented configureRabbitListeners()? Is it possible to register multiple listenerContainer beans without using configureRabbitListeners?

Comment: Does the fact that you recently accepted this answer mean that you solved your latest issue? If not, please provide a small project that exhibits the behavior and I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve the issue. setLookUpKeyQualifier(...) was the main thing that helped solve the issue and so, accepted the answer.